# How to install KdenLive on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, kdenlive

I'm relatively new to Linux and have only used Ubuntu briefly while saving up for a Windows key. I wanted to try out Ubuntu 16 as a replacement for Mac OS X so for an iMovie replacement I wanted to try KdenLive. I was looking around on the website and I couldn't find anything on how to install through the terminal or software center since they are what I'm familiar with. This https://launchpad.net/~kdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-testing is the only page I can find and I haven't a clue how to get packages using pages like this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27):

You *can* install it through the software centre, just search for "Kdenlive" in the software centre, and click Install. You can also install it through the terminal by typing

```
sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```

That's it.

---

Note that you will not get the very latest version by doing this - if you want to have the latest version, you'll need to add the PPA. Do this by typing

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable && sudo apt-get update
```

in a terminal *before* installing it through the software centre or using `apt-get install`

Comment: While I agree that this is the way to do it (adding the ppa first), I'd encourage using the stable PPA instead of the testing one -- the testing packages may contain bugs and aren't always stable. If this sounds like a better option, run this command instead: sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kdenlive

Comment: @Jesse I've edited my answer to use the stable PPA instead the testing one - I don't know why I mentioned the testing one when writing the answer.

Comment: It's all good. :) No worries mate.

Comment: There is a typo. you put "...apt-get get update" and it should be "...apt-get update"

Answer (score 2):

Type this: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-testing`

and then press 'Enter when you are asked to'

Then type this command:`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Then `sudo apt-get install kdenlive`

That's it you are done with it.

There was a small pop-up link leading you through the process of installing stated as 'Read about installing', This same process applies for each and every other 'PPA' named as  Personal Package Archive.

You can learn more about [PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) here.